# Axis error when dropping specific columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have identified specific columns I want to select as my predictors for my model based on some analysis. I have captured those column numbers and stored it in a list. I have roughly 80 columns and want to loop through and drop the columns not in this specific list. X_train is the column in which I want to do this. Here is my code:

```
cols_selected = [24, 4, 7, 50, 2, 60, 46, 53, 48, 61]
cols_drop = []

for x in range(len(X_train.columns)):
    if x in cols_selected:
        pass
    else:
        X_train.drop([x])
```

When running this, I am faced with the following error while highlighting the code: X_train.drop([x]):

> KeyError: '[3] not found in axis'

I am sure it is something very simple that I am missing. I tried including the inplace=True or axis=1 statements along with this and all of them had the same error message (while the value inside the [] changed with those error codes).

Any help would be great!

Edit: Here is the addition to get this working:

```
cols_selected = [24, 4, 7, 50, 2, 60, 46, 53, 48, 61]
cols_drop = []

for x in range(len(X_train.columns)):
    if x in cols_selected:
        pass
    else:
        cols_drop.append(x)

X_train = X_train.drop(X_train.columns[[cols_drop]], axis=1)
```

Comment: There is no visibility of dataset you are talking about, can you show us the DataFrame structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

> Remove rows or columns by specifying label names and corresponding
>   axis, or by specifying directly index or column names

You can not drop columns by simply using the index of the column. You need the name of the columns. Also the `axis` parameter has to be set to `1` or `columns` Replace `X_train.drop([x])` with `X_train=X_train.drop(X_train.columns[x], axis='columns')` to make your example work.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Ran this code, but although it ran it doesn't seem to be dropping any of the columns.

Comment: You need to assign the result to X_train after each drop call

Answer (score 1):

I am just assuming as per the question litle:

Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

Dropping Specific columns `B` & `C`:

```
>>> df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)
# df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1, inplace=True) <-- to make the change the df itself , use inplace=True
   A   D
0  0   3
1  4   7
2  8  11
```

If you are trying to drop them by column numbers (`Dropping by index`) then try like below:

```
>>> df.drop(df.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1)
   A   D
0  0   3
1  4   7
2  8  11
```

OR

```
>>> df.drop(columns=['B', 'C'])
   A   D
0  0   3
1  4   7
2  8  11
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, in addition to @pygo pointing out that df.drop takes a keyword arg to designate the axis, try this:

```
X_train = X_train[[col for col in X_train.columns if col in cols_selected]]
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> cols_selected = ['a', 'c', 'e']
>>> X_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(20, 5)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> X_train
    a  b  c  d  e
0   4  0  3  5  9
1   8  8  6  7  2
2   1  0  2  0  2
3   3  8  0  5  9
4   5  9  7  8  0
5   1  9  3  5  9 ...
>>> X_train = X_train[[col for col in X_train.columns if col in cols_selected]]
>>> X_train
    a  c  e
0   4  3  9
1   8  6  2
2   1  2  2
3   3  0  9
4   5  7  0
5   1  3  9 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Ran this code, but it is returning a dataframe with one column and some values that I do not recognize.

Comment: Oh, alright. Well, I posted a quick example if that helps you -- There is likely another bug somewhere in your code.